# (re)Scanning scsi device works while scanning scsi host doesn't on centOS 6.9

Tags: centos, lvm, scsi

Today I added 1GB of extra space to a virtual disk (basically extended it) in esxi VM. I followed 2 approaches to get the new space recognized:

1. `echo  "- - -"  >  /sys/class/scsi_host/host2/scan`
2. `echo 1  >  /sys/class/scsi_disk/2:0:1:0/device/rescan`

First approach din't work, second one worked.

Any thoughts?

I haven't read documentation in the kernel source tree, that might have what I want.

Comment: See https://communities.vmware.com/thread/492752

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Post the solution and accept it since this could help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

As "val0x00ff" shared the link containing exact answer already:

[communities.vmware.com/thread/492752](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/492752)

> Once you've changed the disk's size in VMware and did not reboot your server, rescan your SCSI devices as such.
>   First, check the name(s) of your scsi devices.
>
> $ ls /sys/class/scsi_device/
>
> Then rescan the scsi bus. Below you can replace the '0:0:0:0′ with the actual scsi bus name found with the previous command. Each colon is prefixed with a slash, which is what makes it look weird.
>
> $ echo 1 > /sys/class/scsi_device/0:0:0:0/device/rescan
>
> That will rescan the current scsi bus and the disk size that has changed will show up.