# LVM Disk creation

Tags: lvm

After creating disks in MX VMware I wanted to use the disk with LVM.

```
echo '- - -' > /sys/bus/scsi/devices/host0/scsi_host/host0/scan
```

Can someone explain what the dashes mean in this code to check that `sda` is created? What exactly is happening here?

Comment: This is a dup answered [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/490397/what-does-in-echo-sys-class-scsi-host-host0-scan-mean)

Comment: Related - [(re)Scanning scsi device works while scanning scsi host doesn't on centOS 6.9](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/400440/100397)

Answer (score 0):

The dashes act as wildcards meaning "rescan everything"

look at the reference on from [redhat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/online_storage_reconfiguration_guide/scanning-storage-interconnects).

> This is the same command described in Section 1.6, “Adding a Storage Device or Path” to add a storage device or path. In this case, however, the channel number, SCSI target ID, and LUN values are replaced by wildcards. Any combination of identifiers and wildcards is allowed, allowing you to make the command as specific or broad as needed. This procedure will add LUNs, but not remove them.